# IIS hosted application logging with NLog in ApplicationData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a RESTful API hosted in the IIS. I would like to write my log files to the `AppData` directory using NLog. But I could not solve my issue to write the log files in the specific directory. If I don't give the permission to the IIS Sites folder, no log file is created by NLog (Not in `AppData` and not in the IIS Sites folder). If I add the user "`IIS AppPool\[IISSiteName]`" and grant this user the write permission, a log file is created in the IIS Sites folder, but not in the `AppData` directory specified in `NLog.config`. When I debug my application locally using IIS Express, there is no problem, only after publishing to the production system.

This is the following file name path which is declared in the `NLog.config`: `${specialfolder:dir=COMPANYNAME:folder=ApplicationData}/APPLICATIONNAME/Logs/NLog/${shortdate}-APPLICATIONAME.log`

Is there any way to log outside the IIS Sites folder?

Comment: You need to spend some time learning Windows folder permissions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/november/access-control-understanding-windows-file-and-registry-permissions and how such permissions propagated via user groups. Your application pool identity needs to be granted all necessary permissions on the target folders, or no log file can be created. IIS Express uses your account so it is less likely to experience permission issues. More in https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Maybe try `${specialfolder:dir=COMPANYNAME:folder=CommonApplicationData}` See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer

Comment: You need to make sure which AppData write in. AppData in the project root folder or  in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData`? It seems that your code will write log into second one. If so, you'd better set application pool to current user which is `<username>`.

Comment: @RolfKristensen this works fine for me but I want to log in die AppData folder and not in the ProgramData directory.

Comment: @BruceZhang I have searched the AppData directories for all users and I have also searched with the tool "Everthing", no log file is created.

Comment: @LexLi In my opinion, I have given all permissions to all directories and added the IIS ApplicationPool user with all permissions in both directories

Comment: @JWhite Maybe try NLog InternalLogger (Debug Level) to diagnose the issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging